# How to I play an .wav file in an <audio> field by setting the source to my Audio field Model(DataBase)?

Tags: javascript, html, django, audio

I haven't been able to find anything online that can help me with this yet. I am trying to play some .wav audio files that I have stored in my Django Model. I am having trouble finding a way to create an instance/query to my database and then being able to use that in my HTML page where my audio field is.

Here is what I have so far...

HTML

---

```
<audio controls id="listen  ">
      <source class="form-control" src="{{  }}" type="audio/wav">        
  </audio>
```

---

Model.py

```
class Media(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    key = models.IntegerField()
    audioFile = models.FileField()
    duration = models.FloatField()

    isPlaying = False
```

---

view.py

```
def  audioPlayer(request):
     return render(request, "Website/myWebSite.html"
```

I am just trying to figure out a way I can set the source on the  tag to pull from the Media Model. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well how do you want to identify which instance of Media you want to play?

Comment: My thoughts were that I would make some sort of query request to the Django DB model, and then use that instance as a source for the <audio> tag but I'm not entirely sure if the way I am trying to go about it is even correct. I am open to any suggestions, I am just trying to find the best way to play an audio file from my model.